# SBT buid error:[error] Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied

Tags: build, sbt, fatal-error, access-denied

I have been  getting server access denied error.Unable to find the fix.Investigated through web.But none of them worked well.I am using windows7.

```
C:\Users\thathine>sbt
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
    port was removed in 8.0
    [info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\thathine\project
    [info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/thathine/project/}thathine-build...
    [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.8 ...
    [error] Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://rep
    o.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/ivys/iv
    y.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://rep
    o.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8
    /ivys/ivy.xml
```

my `buld.sbt`is as follows:

```
name := "spark_codebase"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

I am in need to fix this as soon as possible. Please suggest any solution.Thanks in advance.

Please find the versions of scala, java, sbt:

```
C:\Users\thathine>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131

C:\Users\thathine>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
```

and sbt version is `sbt-0.13.15`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some struggle, found that this issue is because of our company network used some proxy to give restricted access to employees like a firewall. As i was behind a proxy, Maven would fail to download any dependencies.

I got the proxy setings from my companie's IT helpdesk. After using them, It worked finally.I am using windows 7.use the following command line options before using `sbt` for that session,by replacing `[your-ProxyServer]` and `<port-number>` with your actual proxy server and port details.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=[your-ProxyServer] -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port-number> -Dhttps.proxyHost=[your-ProxyServer] -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port-number> -Dftp.proxyHost=[your-ProxyServer] -Dftp.proxyPort=<port-number>
```

**If you are using IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse:**
use the same options under -VM parameters while creating/importing the project.